# Pivot table specific case

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization

I am writing this question because of desperation.

I have the following df:

```py
   FORECAST_DATE  BOOK_SEGMENT_ID               PERIOD_END_P_n_L PERIOD_END_AQR_AVERAGE_BALANCE PERIOD_END_AQR_SPOT_BALANCE
0            Y-1                1     4563737.210000000000000000          33.567583016668937929       41.353567454639780837
1            Y-1                6      315406.100000000000000000           3.061750829952636692        2.522829568693654370
2            Y-1                4    15082237.880000000000000000         138.612207176403403592      181.732357082243759483
3            Y-1                3    43569174.010000000000000000         359.781133882318363070      566.852017680466803209
4            Y-1                2   494389977.810000000000000000        3706.315488833574075112     5882.954828234764105261
5             Y0                1     4626548.470000000000000000          33.463511078561497885       42.108630195163517588
6             Y0                4    57181865.440000000000000000         527.018846167262073635      720.788515365844542397
7             Y0                6     1580093.370000000000000000          14.088379421245762666       16.099449242348320563
8             Y0                3   179134588.050000000000000000        1456.303254133717454069     2216.535521013819977797
9             Y0                2  1845235987.940000000000000000       13967.821066500684233312    22474.822328214837177745
10            Y1                2  1845235987.940000000000000000       13967.821066500684233312    22474.822328214837177745
11            Y1                4    57181865.440000000000000000         527.018846167262073635      720.788515365844542397
12            Y1                3   179134588.050000000000000000        1456.303254133717454069     2216.535521013819977797
13            Y1                6     1580093.370000000000000000          14.088379421245762666       16.099449242348320563
14            Y1                1     4626548.470000000000000000          33.463511078561497885       42.108630195163517588
15            Y2                1     4626548.470000000000000000          33.463511078561497885       42.108630195163517588
16            Y2                2  1845235987.940000000000000000       13967.821066500684233312    22474.822328214837177745
17            Y2                4    57181865.440000000000000000         527.018846167262073635      720.788515365844542397
18            Y2                3   179134588.050000000000000000        1456.303254133717454069     2216.535521013819977797
19            Y2                6     1580093.370000000000000000          14.088379421245762666       16.099449242348320563
20            Y3                4    57181865.440000000000000000         527.018846167262073635      720.788515365844542397
21            Y3                1     4626548.470000000000000000          33.463511078561497885       42.108630195163517588
22            Y3                2  1845235987.940000000000000000       13967.821066500684233312    22474.822328214837177745
23            Y3                6     1580093.370000000000000000          14.088379421245762666       16.099449242348320563
24            Y3                3   179134588.050000000000000000        1456.303254133717454069     2216.535521013819977797
```

**THE DESIRED RESULT IS:**

```py
FORECAST_DATE 
PERIOD_END_P_n_L                             Y-1                             Y0                             Y1                             Y2                             Y3
BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                                                                                                                          
1                  4563737.210000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000
2                494389977.810000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000
3                 43569174.010000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000
4                 15082237.880000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000
6                   315406.100000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000

PERIOD_END_AQR_AVERAGE_BALANCE
BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                                                                                                                          
1                  4563737.210000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000
2                494389977.810000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000
3                 43569174.010000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000
4                 15082237.880000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000
6                   315406.100000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000

PERIOD_END_AQR_SPOT_BALANCE
BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                                                                                                                          
1                  4563737.210000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000
2                494389977.810000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000
3                 43569174.010000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000
4                 15082237.880000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000
6                   315406.100000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000
```

**Please ignore the values, they should be from their respective PERIOD_END_{stat} from the original data frame. What is important is getting the format.**

What I have tried so far:

```py
forecast_summary.pivot(columns="FORECAST_DATE", index="BOOK_SEGMENT_ID")

RESULT:
                             PERIOD_END_P_n_L                                                                                                                             PERIOD_END_AQR_AVERAGE_BALANCE                                                                                                         PERIOD_END_AQR_SPOT_BALANCE                                                                                                        
FORECAST_DATE                             Y-1                             Y0                             Y1                             Y2                             Y3                            Y-1                        Y0                        Y1                        Y2                        Y3                         Y-1                        Y0                        Y1                        Y2                        Y3
BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
1                  4563737.210000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000          33.567583016668937929     33.463511078561497885     33.463511078561497885     33.463511078561497885     33.463511078561497885       41.353567454639780837     42.108630195163517588     42.108630195163517588     42.108630195163517588     42.108630195163517588
2                494389977.810000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000        3706.315488833574075112  13967.821066500684233312  13967.821066500684233312  13967.821066500684233312  13967.821066500684233312     5882.954828234764105261  22474.822328214837177745  22474.822328214837177745  22474.822328214837177745  22474.822328214837177745
3                 43569174.010000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000         359.781133882318363070   1456.303254133717454069   1456.303254133717454069   1456.303254133717454069   1456.303254133717454069      566.852017680466803209   2216.535521013819977797   2216.535521013819977797   2216.535521013819977797   2216.535521013819977797
4                 15082237.880000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000         138.612207176403403592    527.018846167262073635    527.018846167262073635    527.018846167262073635    527.018846167262073635      181.732357082243759483    720.788515365844542397    720.788515365844542397    720.788515365844542397    720.788515365844542397
6                   315406.100000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000           3.061750829952636692     14.088379421245762666     14.088379421245762666     14.088379421245762666     14.088379421245762666        2.522829568693654370     16.099449242348320563     16.099449242348320563     16.099449242348320563     16.099449242348320563
```

```py
forecast_summary.set_index(["BOOK_SEGMENT_ID"], inplace=True).T

RESULT:
BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                          1                          6                            4                            3                             2                           1                            4                           6                             3                              2                              2                            4                             3                           6                           1                           1                              2                            4                             3                           6                            4                           1                              2                           6                             3
FORECAST_DATE                                          Y-1                        Y-1                          Y-1                          Y-1                           Y-1                          Y0                           Y0                          Y0                            Y0                             Y0                             Y1                           Y1                            Y1                          Y1                          Y1                          Y2                             Y2                           Y2                            Y2                          Y2                           Y3                          Y3                             Y3                          Y3                            Y3
PERIOD_END_P_n_L                4563737.210000000000000000  315406.100000000000000000  15082237.880000000000000000  43569174.010000000000000000  494389977.810000000000000000  4626548.470000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000  4626548.470000000000000000  4626548.470000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  4626548.470000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000
PERIOD_END_AQR_AVERAGE_BALANCE       33.567583016668937929       3.061750829952636692       138.612207176403403592       359.781133882318363070       3706.315488833574075112       33.463511078561497885       527.018846167262073635       14.088379421245762666       1456.303254133717454069       13967.821066500684233312       13967.821066500684233312       527.018846167262073635       1456.303254133717454069       14.088379421245762666       33.463511078561497885       33.463511078561497885       13967.821066500684233312       527.018846167262073635       1456.303254133717454069       14.088379421245762666       527.018846167262073635       33.463511078561497885       13967.821066500684233312       14.088379421245762666       1456.303254133717454069
PERIOD_END_AQR_SPOT_BALANCE          41.353567454639780837       2.522829568693654370       181.732357082243759483       566.852017680466803209       5882.954828234764105261       42.108630195163517588       720.788515365844542397       16.099449242348320563       2216.535521013819977797       22474.822328214837177745       22474.822328214837177745       720.788515365844542397       2216.535521013819977797       16.099449242348320563       42.108630195163517588       42.108630195163517588       22474.822328214837177745       720.788515365844542397       2216.535521013819977797       16.099449242348320563       720.788515365844542397       42.108630195163517588       22474.822328214837177745       16.099449242348320563       2216.535521013819977797
```

I have tried numerous combinations and variations with .T .reset_index .set_index .pivot, but have not managed to get the right output table.

If you post different combinations I can try them and say whether it worked and post the result, you do not need to test your variation if you do not want.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I got this close result:

```py
BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                        1                              2                             3                            4                           6
                               FORECAST_DATE                                                                                                                                                  
PERIOD_END_P_n_L               Y-1            4563737.210000000000000000   494389977.810000000000000000   43569174.010000000000000000  15082237.880000000000000000   315406.100000000000000000
                               Y0             4626548.470000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000
                               Y1             4626548.470000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000
                               Y2             4626548.470000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000
                               Y3             4626548.470000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  179134588.050000000000000000  57181865.440000000000000000  1580093.370000000000000000
PERIOD_END_AQR_AVERAGE_BALANCE Y-1                 33.567583016668937929        3706.315488833574075112        359.781133882318363070       138.612207176403403592        3.061750829952636692
                               Y0                  33.463511078561497885       13967.821066500684233312       1456.303254133717454069       527.018846167262073635       14.088379421245762666
                               Y1                  33.463511078561497885       13967.821066500684233312       1456.303254133717454069       527.018846167262073635       14.088379421245762666
                               Y2                  33.463511078561497885       13967.821066500684233312       1456.303254133717454069       527.018846167262073635       14.088379421245762666
                               Y3                  33.463511078561497885       13967.821066500684233312       1456.303254133717454069       527.018846167262073635       14.088379421245762666
PERIOD_END_AQR_SPOT_BALANCE    Y-1                 41.353567454639780837        5882.954828234764105261        566.852017680466803209       181.732357082243759483        2.522829568693654370
                               Y0                  42.108630195163517588       22474.822328214837177745       2216.535521013819977797       720.788515365844542397       16.099449242348320563
                               Y1                  42.108630195163517588       22474.822328214837177745       2216.535521013819977797       720.788515365844542397       16.099449242348320563
                               Y2                  42.108630195163517588       22474.822328214837177745       2216.535521013819977797       720.788515365844542397       16.099449242348320563
                               Y3                  42.108630195163517588       22474.822328214837177745       2216.535521013819977797       720.788515365844542397       16.099449242348320563
```

got it with:

```
forecast_summary.pivot(columns="FORECAST_DATE", index="BOOK_SEGMENT_ID").T
```

Will try now to swap FORECAST_DATE and BOOK_SEGMENT_ID now.

**UPDATE2:**

**ALMOST THERE**

```py
forecast_summary.pivot(columns="FORECAST_DATE", index="BOOK_SEGMENT_ID").T.stack().reset_index(level=1).pivot(columns="FORECAST_DATE")

RESULT:

                                                                           0                                                                                                                            
FORECAST_DATE                                                            Y-1                             Y0                             Y1                             Y2                             Y3
                               BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                                                                                                                          
PERIOD_END_AQR_AVERAGE_BALANCE 1                       33.567583016668937929          33.463511078561497885          33.463511078561497885          33.463511078561497885          33.463511078561497885
                               2                     3706.315488833574075112       13967.821066500684233312       13967.821066500684233312       13967.821066500684233312       13967.821066500684233312
                               3                      359.781133882318363070        1456.303254133717454069        1456.303254133717454069        1456.303254133717454069        1456.303254133717454069
                               4                      138.612207176403403592         527.018846167262073635         527.018846167262073635         527.018846167262073635         527.018846167262073635
                               6                        3.061750829952636692          14.088379421245762666          14.088379421245762666          14.088379421245762666          14.088379421245762666
PERIOD_END_AQR_SPOT_BALANCE    1                       41.353567454639780837          42.108630195163517588          42.108630195163517588          42.108630195163517588          42.108630195163517588
                               2                     5882.954828234764105261       22474.822328214837177745       22474.822328214837177745       22474.822328214837177745       22474.822328214837177745
                               3                      566.852017680466803209        2216.535521013819977797        2216.535521013819977797        2216.535521013819977797        2216.535521013819977797
                               4                      181.732357082243759483         720.788515365844542397         720.788515365844542397         720.788515365844542397         720.788515365844542397
                               6                        2.522829568693654370          16.099449242348320563          16.099449242348320563          16.099449242348320563          16.099449242348320563
PERIOD_END_P_n_L               1                  4563737.210000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000
                               2                494389977.810000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000
                               3                 43569174.010000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000
                               4                 15082237.880000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000
                               6                   315406.100000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000
```

Probably very ugly line of code, but now need to figure out how to drop the 0 from the column headers.

Comment: hmmm, I think you can create 3 different DataFrames for your format, or use `df = forecast_summary.pivot(columns="FORECAST_DATE", index="BOOK_SEGMENT_ID")` and then `print (df.loc['PERIOD_END_P_n_L'])` and similar for each DataFrame

Comment: @jezrael could you print the df and break line at the first level of multiindex in columns? maybe you understand what i mean

Comment: @luigigi - maybe yes, but it is not changed data from `df = forecast_summary.pivot(columns="FORECAST_DATE", index="BOOK_SEGMENT_ID")`, only displayed in some another way ...

Answer (score 0):

After a while...

```py
forecast_summary.set_index(["FORECAST_DATE", "BOOK_SEGMENT_ID"]).T.stack()
```

Produces:

```
FORECAST_DATE                                                            Y-1                             Y0                             Y1                             Y2                             Y3
                               BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                                                                                                                          
PERIOD_END_P_n_L               1                  4563737.210000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000     4626548.470000000000000000
                               2                494389977.810000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000  1845235987.940000000000000000
                               3                 43569174.010000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000   179134588.050000000000000000
                               4                 15082237.880000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000    57181865.440000000000000000
                               6                   315406.100000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000     1580093.370000000000000000
PERIOD_END_AQR_AVERAGE_BALANCE 1                       33.567583016668937929          33.463511078561497885          33.463511078561497885          33.463511078561497885          33.463511078561497885
                               2                     3706.315488833574075112       13967.821066500684233312       13967.821066500684233312       13967.821066500684233312       13967.821066500684233312
                               3                      359.781133882318363070        1456.303254133717454069        1456.303254133717454069        1456.303254133717454069        1456.303254133717454069
                               4                      138.612207176403403592         527.018846167262073635         527.018846167262073635         527.018846167262073635         527.018846167262073635
                               6                        3.061750829952636692          14.088379421245762666          14.088379421245762666          14.088379421245762666          14.088379421245762666
PERIOD_END_AQR_SPOT_BALANCE    1                       41.353567454639780837          42.108630195163517588          42.108630195163517588          42.108630195163517588          42.108630195163517588
                               2                     5882.954828234764105261       22474.822328214837177745       22474.822328214837177745       22474.822328214837177745       22474.822328214837177745
                               3                      566.852017680466803209        2216.535521013819977797        2216.535521013819977797        2216.535521013819977797        2216.535521013819977797
                               4                      181.732357082243759483         720.788515365844542397         720.788515365844542397         720.788515365844542397         720.788515365844542397
                               6                        2.522829568693654370          16.099449242348320563          16.099449242348320563          16.099449242348320563          16.099449242348320563
```

First I set the index of the two columns, then the transpose puts those two columns as column headers. Then the stack, takes the second level and puts it as a column.